# ERROR: getOptRdata - unknown opt 4

Tags: macos, bonjour

I'm getting this error message turning up in the system log, on some Macs, seemingly at random.

```
ERROR: getOptRdata - unknown opt 4
```

It doesn't seem to affect the running of my application, but I'm wondering what's causing it, and whether it could potentially be the cause of other bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

opt 4 for is the EDNS0 'Owner' option.  It allows a server, before sleeping, to ask a sleep proxy for a wake-on-lan if an important packet is sent to the sleeping server.

Older versions of mDNSResponder do not understand this Owner option.

It should not cause any problems other than filling your log files.